# Flag only first instance of a certain period based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to flag only the first day of an uninterrupted period, when a certain customer ID is related to a different location ID.

Now to make myself more clear:
After a customer (`CustId`) leaves a location, we count the number of days the location has not been used, called here `InsuranceDays` by marking the unused days with a '1'. However, it might be that a certain customer switches from location instead of actually ending the entire trip. In that case it should only mark the first day as '1', but not the days afterwards.

So it should somehow check per `CustId` whether in the period afterwards the `CustId` is still related to a certain `loc_Id`. Important here is that the dates should be consecutive. So it only counts as a switch if there is not a single day gap in between. a gap of 1 day actually means ending the trip, and therefore we can count insurance days the easy way we are already doing with column `InsuranceDays`

Below the current dataset `CustomerLocations`:

```
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| Date       | loc_Id   | loc_beginDate | loc_endDate | CustId | CustId_LAST | InsuranceDays |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-05 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-06 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-07 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-08 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-05 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-06 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-07 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-08 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+
```

And the expected results are the following, with the column `InsuranceDays_checkLocation` added:

```
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Date       | loc_Id   | loc_beginDate | loc_endDate | CustId | CustId_LAST | InsuranceDays | InsuranceDays_checkLocation |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-05 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             | 0                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-06 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             | 0                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-07 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             | 0                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-08 | 25010104 | 2021-03-05    | 2099-12-31  | 6911   | 6911        | 0             | 0                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-05 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             | 1                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-06 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             | 0                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-07 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             | 0                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 2021-03-08 | 25010113 | NULL          | 2099-12-31  | NULL   | 6911        | 1             | 0                           |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Unfortunately I have no code as how to tackle this problem. I can imagine we need a window function here, but I don't know how to start. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: column InsuranceDays_checkLocation = the expected result. That's indeed not sufficiently clear. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You need to provide sample starting data and your expected results, as 2 resultsets so that its obvious what the query is meant to do.